# Java / Selenium - Guardar texto em variável

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Gente, tudo bem?

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Preciso gerar um cpf falso, copiar o cpf gerado, e armazená-lo em uma variável. Porém eu não consigo extrair o cpf gerado dos sites que encontrei. Tanto o gettext() quanto o getattribute() não conseguiram localizá-lo. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

http://www.geradordecpf.org/

Comment: Consegui pegar do site tranquilamente através de `$(".btn-default").click(); $("#numero").val();`, mas não seria melhor gerar isso na sua aplicação? Desta maneira, seus testes não ficam condicionados a um outro site.

Comment: @RicardoRodriguesdeFaria e como eu faria isso? Sou novo tanto em java quanto em automação. Me sugeriram fazer isso também, mas não tenho ideia de como e quão complexo é

Comment: Olá Luís@ Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Marquei a pergunta como pendente porque não há informações suficientes para determinar o motivo do Selenium não ter informado. Se precisar de ajuda para isso, poste o código que usou para que possamos analisar. Além disso, a pergunta acabou mudando um pouco o foco para "como gerar um CPF"? Se desejar você pode [edit] sua pergunta para ela ficar coerente com a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Eu não sei como o `Selenium` funciona, mas pelo visto o Ricardo já respondeu a questão de como pegar o `CPF` do site.

Agora, para gerar no seu próprio aplicativo, em `Java`, você deve seguir algumas regras, que estão disponíveis em alguns sites, como [este](http://www.geradorcpf.com/algoritmo_do_cpf.htm).

Eu passei o [site](http://www.geradorcpf.com/algoritmo_do_cpf.htm) para código de maneira extremamente básica:

```
class GeradorDeCPF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] CPFArray = new int[11][3];

        // PREENCHA O CPF ABAIXO, OU NA EXECUCAO DO PROGRAMA

        // String CPFString = "111444777";
        String CPFString = args[0];

        /*
        * LACO PARA TRANSFORMAR O CPF NUM ARRAY DE INTEIROS
        * INCLUIR OS NUMEROS MULTIPLICADORES E FAZER A CONTA
        */

        for (int i = 0; i < CPFString.length(); i++) {


        // CONVERTE CHAR PARA INT E ATRIBUI AO ARRAY
        CPFArray[i][0] = Character.getNumericValue(CPFString.charAt(i));

        // ATRIBUI MULTIPLICADOR AO ARRAY
        CPFArray[i][1] = 10-i;

        // EXECUTA A MULTIPLICACAO
        CPFArray[i][2] = CPFArray[i][0] * CPFArray[i][1];

        }

        // SOMA TODOS OS RESULTADOS
        int somaResultados = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        somaResultados += CPFArray[i][2];
        }

        // CALCULA MODULO
        int moduloDigito1 = somaResultados % 11;
        int digito1 = 0;

        /*
        * SE O MODULO FOR MENOR QUE DOIS, TRANSFORMAR EM ZERO
        * CASO NAO SEJA, SUBTRAIR DE 11 PARA OBTER O PRIMEIRO DIGITO
        */

        if (moduloDigito1 < 2) {
            digito1 = 0;
        } else {
            digito1 = 11 - moduloDigito1;
        }

        // INCLUI O PRIMEIRO DIGITO NO FINAL DO CPF
        CPFArray[9][0] = digito1;        

        // ALTERA OS MULTIPLICADORES
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        // ATRIBUI MULTIPLICADOR AO ARRAY
        CPFArray[i][1] = 11-i;

        // EXECUTA A MULTIPLICACAO
        CPFArray[i][2] = CPFArray[i][0] * CPFArray[i][1];

        }

        // SOMA TODOS OS RESULTADOS
        int somaResultados2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        somaResultados2 += CPFArray[i][2];
        }

        // CALCULA MODULO
        int moduloDigito2 = somaResultados2 % 11;
        int digito2 = 0;

        /*
        * SE O MODULO FOR MENOR QUE DOIS, TRANSFORMAR EM ZERO
        * CASO NAO SEJA, SUBTRAIR DE 11 PARA OBTER O PRIMEIRO DIGITO
        * (E IMPRIME)
        */

        if (moduloDigito2 < 2) {
            digito2 = 0;
        } else {
            digito2 = 11 - moduloDigito2;
        }

        // INCLUI O PRIMEIRO DIGITO NO FINAL DO CPF
        CPFArray[10][0] = digito2;

        // IMPRIME CPF COM DIGITOS

        System.out.print("Digitos verificadores: ");
        System.out.print(CPFArray[9][0] + "" + CPFArray[10][0] + "\n");
    }
}
```

Segue a execução:

[image: Resultado Gerador de CPF]

Agora, se você quiser um `CPF` aleatório, terá que fazer algumas alterações. Importar essas classes no começo:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
```

E alterar o `CPFString` para:

```
int CPFInt = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,999999999 + 1);
DecimalFormat formatador = new DecimalFormat("000000000");
String CPFString = formatador.format(CPFInt);
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado CPF Aleatório]

Lembre-se que este código é só um começo (dá para melhorar BASTANTE), e você ainda precisa fazer ele rodar no `Selenium`!